# RadioGroup in a ScrollView setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-event

Friends,

I have the following xml file:

```
<ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/selector"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:visibility="invisible" >

  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/selector_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp" />
</ScrollView>
```

Which gives me a RadioGroup in a ScrollView such as:

O Radio1Text    whitespace END_OF_SCREEN

O Radio2Text    whitespace END_OF_SCREEN

O Radio3Text    whitespace END_OF_SCREEN

Whenever I click on the text or on the O (RadioButton) the `onCheckedChanged()` is called which is what I want. However, when I click on the whitespace area between the text of the RadioButton and the end of the screen `onCheckedChanged()` is not called. Why is that happening?

If I do not nest the RadioGroup in the ScrollView this does not happen i.e. by clicking on the whitewhitespace area between the text of the RadioButton and the end of the screen `onCheckedChanged()` is not called